# VisualBasic CreateObject()

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a problem with CreateObject. It keeps telling me it's an undeclared element. Is there some specific reference I need to add?

The reference for excel etc are already in it, and don't get any more info from MSDN.

```
Public Function BBANtoBIC(ByVal BBAN As String) As String
        Dim xd As Object
        xd = CreateObject("msxml2.domdocument.4.0")
        xd.Load("http://www.ibanbic.be/IBANBIC.asmx/BBANtoBIC?value=" & BBAN)
        Do While xd.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents()
        Loop
        BBANtoBIC = xd.Text
    End Function
```

Comment: There are far more natural ways to interact with XML from .NET than using old COM components. There are multiple [namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145036.aspx) dedicated to it. I'm sure if you searched for `.NET XML <actual task>` you'd find some far more idomatic code.

Comment: This piece is a part I need to use from my boss, because it's a part in our application, so I can't change it just like that.

Comment: Else I would like some suggestions, I'm new in VB.

Comment: On which line you have undeclared element? I am getting "Cannot create ActiveX component" on xd = ...

Comment: Actually since that is all self contained in a function which returns a string, you CAN use a good NET XML method without changing anything else in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"msxml2.domdocument.4.0" is probably not installed in your system. It it from 2001. You shoud probably use  "Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0". See [Using the right version of MSXML in Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx)

Comment: That was the problem I guess, maybe you can help me with the following error I got for CreateObject: "CreateObject cannot be used to create instances of classes in Visual Basic unless those classes are explicitly exposed as COM components."

Comment: @Marijke I am not able to reproduce the exception. But it seems that you are either really trying to create not explicitly exposed class or the registry information for the class is corrupt. You should be able to see record in registry e.g.  Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0 is in HKCR\CLSID\{88d96a05-f192-11d4-a65f-0040963251e5}. I would compare records with register in other computer or try to reregister .dll (%SystemRoot%\System32\msxml6.dll). I can also be some combination of x86 and x64 architectures.  To find what is going on more detailed information is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through that function, all it does is return the text of the document. It doesn't really do anything with the xml. Therefore, you could replace it with this:

```
Public Function BBANtoBIC(ByVal BBAN As String) As String
    Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient()
        Return wc.DownloadString("http://www.ibanbic.be/IBANBIC.asmx/BBANtoBIC?value=" & BBAN)
    End Using
End Function
```

I see only two reasons why this might not be true. The first is if you're counting the on xml document object to ensure that what you download really is valid, well-formed xml, in which case there should be error handling code near where the function is called. The second is if the `DoEvents` wait-loop is there for program responsiveness rather than waiting on the xml parser... which is also very poor design. Using DoEvents() in that way can have side effects. If it's *only* about waiting on the xml parser, the new code should avoid that delay entirely.

If you do need to parse/validate the xml, there are at least three different ways built-into the .Net framework to do this without needing to rely on `CreateObject()`. There should be no need to use `CreateObject()` in .Net. **Ever**